# How to upload files using NET CORE and Refit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, refit

When I use a POSTMAN to do make a request, my API receives a `IList<IFormFile>`.

[image: Request using POSTMAN]

[image: API]

How can I do the same request using Xamarin.Forms with [REFIT](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `IEnumerable<StreamPart>` to upload a list of files:

```
public interface IApi
{
    [Multipart]
    [Post("/api/story/{id}/upload-images")]
    Task UploadImages(int id, [AliasAs("files")] IEnumerable<StreamPart> streams);
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
var api = RestService.For<ISomeApi>("http://localhost:61468");
var files = new List<StreamPart>()
{
    new StreamPart(fileStream, "photo.jpg", "image/jpeg"),
    new StreamPart(fileStream2, "photo2.jpg", "image/jpeg")
};

await api.UploadImages(1, files);
```

Comment: if it helps anyone documentation is here: https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#multipart-uploads