# Refit upload file from Api to Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, refit

I am trying to upload an image from one Asp net core backend to an other via refit.

```
await _repository.UploadImageAsync(userId,
    new StreamPart(file.OpenReadStream(), file.FileName, file.ContentType), extension);
```

The Api

```
[Put("/image/{userId}")]
Task<Guid> UploadImageAsync(Guid userId, StreamPart stream, string extension);
```

The receiving Controller

```
[HttpPut("image/{userId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImageAsync([FromRoute] Guid userId, StreamPart stream, string extension)
{
    return await RunAsync(async () =>
    {
        var id = await _userImageManager.UploadImageAsync(userId, stream.Value, extension);

        return Ok(id);
    });
}
```

As soon as I run this i get the following exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ReferenceReadStream'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
   at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Refit.JsonContentSerializer.SerializeAsync[T](T item) in d:\a\1\s\Refit\JsonContentSerializer.cs:line 34
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<<BuildRequestFactoryForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in d:\a\1\s\Refit\RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 546
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in d:\a\1\s\Refit\RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 243
```

I tried going the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253505/how-to-upload-files-using-net-core-and-refit) but had no success. Is there anything I did wrong?

## EDIT

Based on @TomO answer I edited my code, but I still get null for `stream`:

Api 1 (the sending part to Api 2):

```
public async Task<Guid> UploadImageAsync(Guid userId, IFormFile file)
{
    ...
    var stream = file.OpenReadStream();

    var streamPart = new StreamPart(stream, file.FileName, file.ContentType);
    var response = await _repository.UploadImageAsync(userId,
                streamPart, extension);
    ...
}
```

Api 2 (The receiver):

```
[HttpPost("image/{userId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImageAsync([FromRoute] Guid userId, string description, IFormFile stream, string extension)
{
    ...
}
```

The Refit Api:

```
[Multipart]
[Post("/image/{userId}")]
Task<Guid> UploadImageAsync(Guid userId, [AliasAs("Description")] string description, [AliasAs("File")] StreamPart stream, string extension);
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm struggling to handle a very similar situation. Can't seem to get a multipart form data upload with a file part.

Comment: Actually no, I paused the dev of this api until now, but haven't had luck

Comment: I think you might want to change your refit argument list to AliasAs("stream") instead of "File" given your API is looking for a variable named "stream" and not "File" like my case - hopefully just a cut&paste error. Would certainly explain why your stream is coming in as null.

Comment: oops, yes, this was a copy paste & brain AFK error, sorry.. Renaming the variable fixed the issue! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the documentation (and the solution linked in the question) give good guidance. But here's what I got to work, anyhow:

Receiving API endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{*filePath:regex(^.*\\.[[^\\\\/]]+[[A-Za-z0-9]]$)}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile([FromRoute] AddFileRequest request,
                                         [FromForm] AddFileRequestDetails body,
                                         CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

And the corresponding refit client call:

```
[Multipart]
[Post("/{**filePath}")]
Task AddFile(string filePath, [AliasAs("Description")] string description, [AliasAs("File")] StreamPart filepart);
```

**The important thing here is that ALL of the member properties of the Form body(not including file) have to be decorated with the "AliasAs" attribute.**

Calling on the sending side:

```
            System.IO.Stream FileStream = request.File.OpenReadStream();
            StreamPart sp = new StreamPart(FileStream, request.FileName);

            try
            {
                await _filesClient.AddFile(request.FilePath, request.Description, sp);
            }
            catch (ApiException ae)
            {
                ...
                throw new Exception("Refit FileClient API Exception", ae);
            }
```

Hope this helps the next person...

Comment: Still had no luck with your answer, what does the receiving Api controller look like? Does it receive a StreamPart or IFormFile?

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin IFormFile. StreamPart is merely for the refit piece, but the controller should (at least in my case) stand alone as a standard Multipart Form upload.

Comment: The receiving API is the first codeblock, where AddFileRequest (the route object) just contains the string FilePath. The AddFileRequestDetails (form object) contains a string Description and IFormFile File.

Comment: Then I still don't get it to work.. I updated my question with the new code